# How to append dynamic array key to another array key

Tags: php

Sorry for the bad title, it's really hard to describe,

```
$x['is']['tall'] = 'yes';
$y['personal']['age'] = 30;
```

I have dynamic array keys, and I want to it append to another array key, the result is like

```
$main['profile']['is']['tall'] = 'yes';                                                                                                                                                                         
$main['profile']['personal']['age'] = 30;
```

cause when I use `json_encode` I want to the structure like `{"profile":{"is":{"tall":"yes"},"personal":{"age":30}}}`

I don't know how to extend the array key like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

```
$x['is']['tall'] = 'yes';
$y['personal']['age'] = 30;
```

Then you can just merge $x and $y to $main like:

```
$main['profile'] = array_merge($x, $y);

var_dump($main);

echo json_encode($main);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["profile"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["is"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["tall"]=>
      string(3) "yes"
    }
    ["personal"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["age"]=>
      int(30)
    }
  }
}
{"profile":{"is":{"tall":"yes"},"personal":{"age":30}}}
```

https://3v4l.org/3CREt

Comment: Yeah. I think I need more coffee. This is how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [array _merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) or[`array_push`.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)